# Stacked bar graph from pivot table that is grouped by month?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart based on the below pivot table. I need each bar to represent a month and within the bar the distribution of each category type.

No matter what data range I choose (aggregate or not), each category and month gets it own individual bar, ie: I get a bar for Jan Cat3, Jan Cat1, Jan Cat2 and Jan Total 12.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sort of pivot table can be created with https://www.koia.io.
The source code is on https://github.com/centeractive/koia

In koia you use your data and create your pivot table as you have it now.

In the upper right corner (see picture) of your pivot table, you can choose to visualize it as different charts.

Your data will NOT be uploaded to koia, but stay local and save on your machine.

Just choose the option stacked bar chart and Koia will automatically create it.
[image]